# Three.js: scene snapshot excluding a particular object

Tags: three.js, snapshot, watermark

I have a three.js scene. There are some objects including a watermark object. I need to take a scene snapshot but it should not include the watermark object. But at the same time a user should not see the scene without watermark on his screen so he could not take a screenshot.
Is it possible and how?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/) is a fiddle that shows how to take a screenshot.
[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/art388yv/5/) is a version that hides the mesh before the screenshot is taken.

Original function.

```
function takeScreenshot() {
    var w = window.open('', '');
    w.document.title = "Screenshot";
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
    w.document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Altered function to hide mesh.

```
function takeScreenshot() {
    var w = window.open('', '');
    w.document.title = "Screenshot";
    var img = new Image();
    mesh.visible = false;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    img.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
    mesh.visible = true;
    w.document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

I just set the mesh to visible = false, render the scene to take the screenshot, then set mesh.visible back to true.